# upstart script not logging to file

Tags: linux, upstart

Linux CentOS 6.5

Here's my upstart script inside of `/etc/init/`

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

exec /usr/bin/riofs --fuse-options="allow_other" --fmode=0777 --dmode=0777 ct.recordergo /mnt/applications/recorder/streams/_definst_/s3
```

I want to run this program once on startup.

I get no logs inside of `/var/log/upstart`.

I'm not sure if the script is working or not. How can get it to log a success or failure?

Comment: Where have you located this script ?

Comment: @Iain `/etc/init`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable debugging to the system log with the `initctl log-priority <priority>` command.

> To change the priority with which Upstart logs messages to the system
>   log, you can change the log priority at any time using log-priority
>   command as follows:
>
> ```
> initctl log-priority <priority>
> ```
>
> Where `<priority>` may be one of:
>
> debug, info, message, warn, error, fatal

See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#debugging for more information

Answer (score 1):

The version of Upstart in centos is very old (v0.6.5 from 2010) and does not have logging support. Use the work-around as documented in the Upstart Cookbook:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#versions-of-upstart-older-than-1-4

Comment: This is for an Ubuntu server. I'm not running an Ubuntu server, and thus, I don't have the /dev/.initramfs directory that the directions are telling me to write logs to. When I tried this it didn't work